# How to figure out SCSI_ID on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, hard-disk, scsi

I am running into an issue on a server I am building into a template for Oracle on Red Hat 7. I can't seem to pull in my SCSI IDs of hard drives. Here is what I have tried so far.

[root@rhel7asm12ctemplate by-id]# lsscsi --scsi_id

[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00  /dev/sr0   -

[2:0:0:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sda   -

[2:0:1:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdb   -

[2:0:2:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdc   -

/dev/disk/by-id
Does not show anything for SCSI_ID but does show me uuid.

[root@rhel7asm12ctemplate ~]# /usr/lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --replace-whitespace --device=/dev/sda

returns nothing as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to get the SCSI ID I need for ASM?

Thanks!

Comment: udevadm info <diskpath> | grep ID_SCSI will give you the SCSI ID

Comment: [root@rhel7asm12ctemplate udev]# udevadm info /dev/sda | grep ID_SCSI
E: ID_SCSI=1
This is what I received back when I test that.

Comment: Is it a scsi disk? maybe it's sata?

Comment: Definitely SCSI Disks. Running in vSphere 6.0

Comment: You can set a flag in the .vmx file to make Linux see scsi_ids: http://virtuallyhyper.com/2012/03/missing-links-to-devices-on-linux-vms-under-devdiskby-id/

Answer (score 1):

```
[root@rhel7asm12ctemplate by-id]# lsscsi --scsi_id
[1:0:0:0] cd/dvd NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00 /dev/sr0 -
[2:0:0:0] disk VMware Virtual disk 1.0 /dev/sda -
[2:0:1:0] disk VMware Virtual disk 1.0 /dev/sdb -
[2:0:2:0] disk VMware Virtual disk 1.0 /dev/sdc -
```

This output tells me the following:

- storage controller #1 is a VMware virtual IDE bus, and it has only the virtual CD/DVD drive. For SCSI compatibility, that drive is presented as SCSI bus #0, target #0, LUN #0 on that controller.
- storage controller #2 is the VMware virtual SCSI controller. On it, there are three disks, all on virtual bus #0: their virtual SCSI target IDs are 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

If you are trying to find out the *physical* SCSI bus/target/LUN triplets from the inside of a VMware virtual machine, that's a non-starter: VMware explicitly hides those details of the physical host from the VM. Neither the operating system nor Oracle ASM within the VM can see the real SCSI target IDs of the actual hardware.

As Mark Plotnick commented, adding `disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"` to the `.vmx` file of the virtual machine will either pass through (for "raw" physical LUNs) or generate (for VMware virtual disks hosted in VMware datastores) unique, persistent WWIDs for any disks presented to the VM. After the setting has been changed, the VM needs to be powered down and restarted to make the change effective.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  You need to have the `iscsi-initiator-utils` package installed.
Execute the following command:

```
/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb
```

You'll want to change the `/dev` path to the appropriate `sd*` partition.
To see the drives, you may need to create a `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules` file.